# Bazel- issue importing header files

Tags: c++, build, bazel

I am trying to import these Header files:

```
AffdexException.h  Detector.h  FaceListener.h   Frame.h          
PhotoDetector.h          typedefs.h
CameraDetector.h   Face.h      FrameDetector.h  ImageListener.h  
ProcessStatusListener.h  VideoDetector.h
```

They are located under the /root/affdex-sdk/include. Here is what my base WORKSPACE file looks like:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "Boost",
  path = "/usr/local/lib/",
  build_file = "/usr/local/lib/BUILD.boost",
)

new_local_repository(
  name = "OpenCV",
  path = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/",
  build_file = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/BUILD.opencv",
)

new_local_repository(
  name = "AffdexSDK",
  path = "/root/affdex-sdk/",
  build_file = "/root/affdex-sdk/BUILD.affectiva",
)
```

The issue is with the AffdexSDK header files. Here is my BUILD.affectiva:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

cc_library(
  name = "affdex-sdk",
  srcs = glob(["**/*.so"]),
  hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
)
```

and the BUILD file with my main target I want to turn into a binary:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "video-detector",
    srcs = ["vidDetector.cpp", "include/VideoDetector.h"],
    deps = ["@AffdexSDK//:affdex-sdk",
            "@Boost//:boost",
            "@OpenCV//:opencv",
    ],
    includes = [":affdex-sdk/include/"],
)
```

And the declarations for the main source code file I need to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

#include </root/affdex-sdk/include/VideoDetector.h>
#include </root/affdex-sdk/include/PhotoDetector.h>
#include </root/affdex-sdk/include/AffdexException.h>

#include "/root/sdk-samples/common/PlottingImageListener.hpp"
#include "/root/sdk-samples/common/StatusListener.hpp"
```

And when I run the command bazel build //affdex-sdk:video-detector --verbose_failures:

I get this error:

```
ERROR: /root/affdex-sdk/BUILD:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//affdex-sdk:video-detector':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'affdex-sdk/vidDetector.cpp':
 
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/VideoDetector.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/FrameDetector.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/Detector.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/typedefs.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/ImageListener.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/Face.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/Frame.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/FaceListener.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/ProcessStatusListener.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/AffdexException.h'
      '/root/affdex-sdk/include/PhotoDetector.h'
      '/root/sdk-samples/common/PlottingImageListener.hpp'
      '/root/sdk-samples/common/StatusListener.hpp'
```

So I am not sure why these aren't being included because I am getting these header files via glob in BUILD.affectiva. I used absolute paths in the declaration for vidDetector.cpp because it was not fetching them otherwise. I am not sure how to include the sdk-samples/common hpp files, but I would assume the other header files in affdex-sdk are included via glob in BUILD.affectiva. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the nice way how to debug issues like this is to look what is copied into your sandbox. There is a [blog post](https://blog.bazel.build/2016/03/18/sandbox-easier-debug.html) on the topic.

Now to your particular problem, I think you should put `includes` attribute to the `@AffdexSDK//:affdex-sdk` rule and remove it from `:video-detector`. Then you should be able to reference the headers relative to their include directory, e.g. `#include <Detector.h>`.

You can also use
[strip_include_prefix](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.strip_include_prefix) and [include_prefix](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.include_prefix) attribtues to tweak the includes path to your preference.